# Problemas con JavaFX y su librería " javafx.scene.media " problemas al importar módulos IntelliJ

Tags: javafx, maven, intellij-idea, mediaplayer

Les escribo ya que llevo bastante tiempo batallando con intellij y su module-info.java. Que entiendo es por donde vienen los problemas
Estoy tratando de reproducir un mp3 con la clase Media y MediaPlayer. Pero solo de instanciar la clase me tira abajo el programa arrojandome
un error de "IlllegalStatus" y un apartado que creo es el mas importante pero que no se resolver y es el siguiente:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.PlatformManager (in module javafx.media) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil (in module javafx.base) because module javafx.base does not export com.sun.javafx to module javafx.media`

Answer (score 0):

Revisa si cargastes bien en el intellij todos los modulos.
Aca te dejo. Yo uso openFx 17.0.1 y no tengo problemas.
Revisa esta solución

```
Run -> Edit Configuration -> Application -> tu aplicacion
```

puedes agregar estas lineas para cargar todos los modulos. Se supone que en la carpeta donde esta el JDK de javafx están esas librerias.

```
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web,javafx.swt
```

Answer (score -1):

Solucionado. No es recomendable usar versiones muy nuevas de "JavaFX Media". He optado por usar la versión 14. No me funcionó con la 18, ni 17 ni 16.